# Does Jabber/XMPP got a prefered database?

Tags: xmpp

Right now i am developing an app for a real time chat communication that need to make an authentication of the users.
I read at various places that XMPP makes an authentication but i need to find out the database he works with , so does anybode know ?
Or can he make authentication of the users with any database? 
Thanks

Comment: You really should learn how XMPP works and what it does first. Then take a look at some implementations.

Comment: arkascha thanks but i already learned about the protocol and how it works , maybe i missed something but i need to find out the XMPP prefered database do you know it by any chance?

Comment: You kind of answered your question yourself, or better pointed out why the question does not make sense: XMPP is a protocol, a protocol does not use a database. An implementation might connect to and use a database.